# How to debug a non functioning email validation rule?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, validation, validationrules

I've added a custom validation rule to check email validity on a WPF textbox. The rule is derived from the [System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule(v=vs.110).aspx) abstract class.

But when I enter an incorrect email, such as "fjhglkfkhj" and tab to the next textbox, no red box or error message shows as usual.

I checked over the settings on the textbox and the validation rule, which both seem correct. Also the namespace to the rule is correct as per my project folder structure. I also checked other [solutions on implementing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753962(v=vs.100).aspx) the rule but mine doesn't work.

Can anyone advise on how to debug this further? Or where I could be missing something in the set up?

This is the `RegexValidationRule` that the text box error checking binds to:

```
namespace MongoDBApp.Validator
{
    public class RegexValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {

       private string Message = "Incorrect email format, please enter a valid email!";
       Regex Regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
      {
        if(Regex.IsMatch((string)value))
          return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        else
          return new ValidationResult(false, Message);
      }
    }
}
```

And this is how I've set the binding in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MongoDBApp.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:email_validator="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Validator"
        Title="Orders Dashbord"
        Width="800"
        Height="500">

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Customer">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height=".50*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>




                    <TextBox x:Name="emailTbx"
                             Grid.Row="6"
                             Grid.Column="2"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             Width="120"
                             Height="23"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding ElementName="customersgrid"
                                     Path="SelectedItem.Email"
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <email_validator:RegexValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                                </Binding.ValidationRules>
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>


                </Grid>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Order" />

            <TabItem Header="OrderStatus" />
            <TextBlock Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Text="TextBlock"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: TextBoxes don’t have a default style for validation errors, you need to set them yourself. You can create a trigger on `Validation.HasError`; search for WPF error adorner to see some examples.

Comment: @BrianJ, in regards to poke's comment.. did you set a break point on the if conditional statement and evaluate which code block (statement) is executed?

Comment: Find a better regex, you have not been able to limit TLDs to 3 characters for a long time ...

Comment: generic TLDs (gTLD).. `.system` being among my favs to use

Comment: Okay so I added an adorner to the textbox and it's showing the correct error info. But I did notice by setting a break point, the validation rule only fires on an email selected from data grid. If I input new data before selecting any record from the grid, the rule never fires. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Please don't change your question after it's asked, either by editing the question itself or by adding new questions in the comments. It seems that the question above is best closed as "typographical error" (i.e. you just forgot to include the code that would do what you wanted). If you have a _new_ question about how to use that code, please post a new question. Be sure to include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, with a precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho ok I'll post a more relevant question once I've figured out the a reliable reproduction of the new issue. For now, I'm happy to close this question as I resolved the issue myself.